# Debugging PySpark udf (lambda function using datetime)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I came across- the below lambda code line in PySpark while browsing a long python Jupyter notebook, I am trying to understand this piece of line. Can you explain what it does in a best possible way?

```
parse =  udf (lambda x: (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours= x)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z', StringType())
```

Comment: you should try running it on python to test as they're not spark specific functions. `utcnow()` gives the current datetime, `timedelta()` will create a delta object that can be added or subtracted to/from the current datetime. The rest of the part is to format the datetime as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
udf(
    lambda x: (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=x)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z',
    StringType()
)
```

[`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) in PySpark assigns a *Python* function which is run for every row of Spark df.

> Creates a user defined function (UDF).
>
> *New in version 1.3.0.*
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **f** : *function*
>   python function if used as a standalone function
> - **returnType** : *[pyspark.sql.types.DataType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.DataType.html#pyspark.sql.types.DataType) or str*
>   the return type of the user-defined function. The value can be either a [pyspark.sql.types.DataType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.DataType.html#pyspark.sql.types.DataType) object or a DDL-formatted type string.

The `returnType` will be a string. Removing it, we get the function body we're interested in:

```
lambda x: (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=x)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
```

In order to find out what the given lambda function does, you can create a regular function from it. You may need to add imports too.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def func(x):
    return (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours= x)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
```

To really see what's going on you can create variables out of every element and `print` them.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def my_func(x):
    v1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    v2 = timedelta(hours=x)
    v3 = v1 - v2
    v4 = v3.isoformat()
    v5 = v4[:-3]
    v6 = v5 + 'Z'

    [print(e) for e in (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)]
    
    return v6

print(my_func(3))

# 2022-06-17 07:16:36.212566
# 3:00:00
# 2022-06-17 04:16:36.212566
# 2022-06-17T04:16:36.212566
# 2022-06-17T04:16:36.212
# 2022-06-17T04:16:36.212Z
```

This way you see how result changes after every step. You can `print` whatever you want at any step you need. E.g. `print(type(v4))`